# How to create and attach to email multiple PDFs using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm using iTextSharp and I was wondering, how do I send multiple PDFs as attachments?
Also does it work in Azure? Thanks in advance, I appreciate it.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: This is not really azure specific. Nothing should stop you from using iTextSharp, SmtpClient and MailMessage. You will need an SMTP service for properly sending mail from azure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used iTextSharp in Azure for over a year without any problems.

You'll probably want to use a third party email service to prevent emails from being caught in spam filters.  I'd recommend using Amazon SES (Simple Email Service).  It's cheap and reliable.  That being said, you'll have to read the documentation of the third party email service you end up using to see how to work with email attachments.

For reference, [here is a post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/10/08/adoption-program-insights-sending-emails-from-windows-azure-part-1-of-2.aspx) from the Windows Azure blog that lists three ways to send emails from Azure.  I mentioned #3 above.  The other two methods require you to use an on-premise email server.